# can't exit event handler

Tags: java, binance

I am making a bot for binance using java. for this I found a library for binance websocket binance4j. I managed to open a websocket, but I don't know how to terminate it under certain conditions.

library documentation
https://binance4j.github.io/binance4j/binance4j-documentation/docs/websocket

my code

```
public class Timer {
     private static String symbol = "btcusdt".toUpperCase();
     
     public Timer(CandlestickInterval interval) {
              WebsocketCandlestickClient client = new WebsocketCandlestickClient(symbol, interval);

              client.open();
    
              client.onMessage(cb -> {
        
                   if (cb.getIsBarFinal()) {
                   //when the candle closes
                   //close the connection and transfer execution to the main function
                   
                   }

              });

      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation you already referenced](https://binance4j.github.io/binance4j/binance4j-documentation/docs/websocket) you can call:

```
//Before closing, the `onClosing` handler will be called, then `onClosed` once the connection is closed.
client.close();
```

Also you should set handler first, only then open the connection:

```
client.onMessage(cb -> ...
client.open();
```

Comment: unfortunately the thread of execution ends, but the execution is not transferred to the main function. i put the client.close() inside the condition

Comment: @AnSill Is your handler even invoked? You are setting handler only after opening connection.

Comment: I did so 
client.onMessage(cb -> ...
client.open(); 
and in the handler i put client.close()